# Python POST request returns just part of the result

Tags: python, curl, post, request, here-api

I'm using HERE MAP API:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/geocoder/multi-reverse-geocode-landmarks

When I use curl request like that:

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: *' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -d 'id=0001&prox=52.5309,13.3845,500
id=002&prox=52.5509,13.3945,500' \
  'https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/multi-reversegeocode.json?mode=retrieveLandmarks&gen=9&maxresults=1&app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE'*
```

I'm getting the correct response:

---

{"Response":{"MetaInfo":{"Timestamp":"2020-02-11T20:52:22.096+0000"},"Item":[{"ItemId":1,"Result":[{"Relevance":1.0,"Distance":161.2,"MatchLevel":"landmark","MatchQuality":{"Country":1.0,"State":1.0,"County":1.0,"City":1.0,"District":1.0,"Street":[1.0],"HouseNumber":1.0,"PostalCode":1.0,"Name":1.0},"Location":{"LocationId":"NT_2tJfMbwzYPMKlNdDmb5jBB_p_bUfMBOrFIallcDBNjbQ6VD","LocationType":"cemetery","Name":"Dorotheenstädtischer Friedhof","DisplayPosition":{"Latitude":52.52877,"Longitude":13.38299},"NavigationPosition":[{"Latitude":52.52882,"Longitude":13.38524}],"MapView":{"TopLeft":{"Latitude":52.5298942,"Longitude":13.3811422},"BottomRight":{"Latitude":52.5276458,"Longitude":13.3848378}},"Address":{"Label":"Chausseestraße 126, 10115 Berlin, Deutschland","Country":"DEU","State":"Berlin","County":"Berlin","City":"Berlin","District":"Mitte","Street":"Chausseestraße","HouseNumber":"126","PostalCode":"10115","AdditionalData":[{"value":"Deutschland","key":"CountryName"},{"value":"Berlin","key":"StateName"},{"value":"Berlin","key":"CountyName"}]},"MapReference":{"MapId":"UWAM19149","MapVersion":"Q1/2019","MapReleaseDate":"2020-01-24","CountryId":"20147700","StateId":"20187401","CountyId":"20187402","CityId":"20187403","DistrictId":"20187417","PlaceId":"898512796"}}}]},{"ItemId":2,"Result":[{"Relevance":1.0,"Distance":-36.1,"MatchLevel":"landmark","MatchQuality":{"Country":1.0,"State":1.0,"County":1.0,"City":1.0,"District":1.0,"Street":[1.0],"HouseNumber":1.0,"PostalCode":1.0,"Name":1.0},"Location":{"LocationId":"NT_kVPSoMMfo8QWTG-W48-JrD_p_CHPEQ-9guKqwHPBzIZyhkB","LocationType":"park","Name":"Sportplatz Wedding","DisplayPosition":{"Latitude":52.5512,"Longitude":13.394},"NavigationPosition":[{"Latitude":52.55056,"Longitude":13.39432}],"MapView":{"TopLeft":{"Latitude":52.5523242,"Longitude":13.3921512},"BottomRight":{"Latitude":52.5500758,"Longitude":13.3958488}},"Address":{"Label":"Behmstraße 29, 13357 Berlin, Deutschland","Country":"DEU","State":"Berlin","County":"Berlin","City":"Berlin","District":"Gesundbrunnen","Street":"Behmstraße","HouseNumber":"29","PostalCode":"13357","AdditionalData":[{"value":"Deutschland","key":"CountryName"},{"value":"Berlin","key":"StateName"},{"value":"Berlin","key":"CountyName"}]},"MapReference":{"MapId":"UWAM19149","MapVersion":"Q1/2019","MapReleaseDate":"2020-01-24","CountryId":"20147700","StateId":"20187401","CountyId":"20187402","CityId":"20187403","DistrictId":"20428239","PlaceId":"1109857527"}}}]}]}}

---

But when I do the same from python request lib I'm getting only the last item from the response:

```
import requests
import json

URL = "https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/multi-reversegeocode.json

headers = {'content-type': '*', "Cache-Control": "no-cache"}

data = [('id', '0001'), ('prox', '52.5309,13.3845,500'),
        ('id', '0002'), ('prox', '52.5509,13.3945,500')]
params = {
    "app_id": <APP_ID>,
    "app_code": <APP_CODE>,
    "mode": "retrieveLandmarks",
    "maxresults": 1,
    "gen": 9,
}

res = requests.post(URL, params=params, data=data, headers=headers)
print(res.json())
```

{'Response': {'MetaInfo': {'Timestamp': '2020-02-11T20:53:58.558+0000'}, 'Item': [{'ItemId': 2, 'Result': [{'Relevance': 1.0, 'Distance': -36.1, 'MatchLevel': 'landmark', 'MatchQuality': {'Country': 1.0, 'State': 1.0, 'County': 1.0, 'City': 1.0, 'District': 1.0, 'Street': [1.0], 'HouseNumber': 1.0, 'PostalCode': 1.0, 'Name': 1.0}, 'Location': {'LocationId': 'NT_kVPSoMMfo8QWTG-W48-JrD_p_CHPEQ-9guKqwHPBzIZyhkB', 'LocationType': 'park', 'Name': 'Sportplatz Wedding', 'DisplayPosition': {'Latitude': 52.55056, 'Longitude': 13.39432}, 'MapView': {'TopLeft': {'Latitude': 52.5516842, 'Longitude': 13.3924713}, 'BottomRight': {'Latitude': 52.5494358, 'Longitude': 13.3961687}}, 'Address': {'Label': 'Behmstraße 29, 13357 Berlin, Deutschland', 'Country': 'DEU', 'State': 'Berlin', 'County': 'Berlin', 'City': 'Berlin', 'District': 'Gesundbrunnen', 'Street': 'Behmstraße', 'HouseNumber': '29', 'PostalCode': '13357', 'AdditionalData': [{'value': 'Deutschland', 'key': 'CountryName'}, {'value': 'Berlin', 'key': 'StateName'}, {'value': 'Berlin', 'key': 'CountyName'}]}, 'MapReference': {'CountryId': '20147700', 'StateId': '20187401', 'CountyId': '20187402', 'CityId': '20187403', 'DistrictId': '20428239', 'PlaceId': '1109857527'}}}]}]}}

How can I get the full result?

Comment: `maxresults: 1` means you only want one result. I'm not sure why it's ignoring that in your `curl` version, though.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the `curl` command correctly? There should be `&` before `id=002`, not a newline. Maybe it didn't really have `maxresults=1` in it. You're also missing `"gen": "9"` in `params`.

Comment: @Barmar "maxresults: 1" - doesn't mean one result. I added "gen": 9. Same issue.

Comment: What does it mean? Can you link to the API documentation?

Comment: @Barmar I've added the link at the beginning.

Comment: Did you try sending data as an constructed string instead of relying on requests to do it for you? Use urlencode() to do it and send it as Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded,
because it is possible that requests is sending it as  multipart/form-data, now and API might not like it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to pass `data` as a string instead. It looks like second line in `data` was ignored. curl's -d option does not alter or encode the data at all but will just send exactly what you tell it to.

```
import requests

url = "https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/multi-reversegeocode.json?mode=retrieveLandmarks&gen=9&maxresults=1&app_id=<APP_ID>&app_code=<APP_CODE>"

payload = "id=0001&prox=52.5309,13.3845,500\nid=002&prox=52.5509,13.3945,500\n"
headers = {
  'Content-Type': '*'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
```

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/9068895/alex-mrynskyi. Thank you! It works. 
I wonder to know what is wrong with dict/list way...
In according to https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests
it should work.

Comment: if you look how requests is encoding data you will see something like `body = self._encode_params(data)` and result will be

'id=0001&prox=52.5309%2C13.3845%2C500&id=0002&prox=52.5509%2C13.3945%2C500'

Comment: If you specify the Content-Type header to be application/x-www-urlencoded the requests library will compile the POST data accordingly and deliver it in one shot. It is not unreasonable from the API to reject the first way as it increases the server's resistance to the DoS attacks.

Comment: @Dalen sorry, but requests doesn't work like this. It will  if you look into the implementation https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/a9906536ee971872e5031a0138d63fb4ea481511/requests/models.py#L507 you will notice that _encode_params always encodes params if `hasattr(data, '__iter__')` regardless of the Content-Type. You could use `files` but it will give you completely different result. You could use files and multipart/form-data - but result will be completely different https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2. We just need to pass data as it is.

Comment: @Alex : Yes, we need to, as I pointed out from the start. And it would be better if dict() is used and encoded using urllib.urlencode() instead of constructing the data strings. Simply better practice and more flexibility. As for rest, I just speculated what may or may not be happening. I have no time to examine the library which I do not need as there are urllib, urllib2 and urllib3. Especially for such little tasks as posting few bytes and which requires no sessions and other nifty stuff requests is supposed to help with.